# Swift - access UIButton inside ContainerView in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I am having a problem accessing my `UIButton` that's inside a `ContainerView` from another `ViewController`.

If the user taps the `button` a `SubView` should appear inside of my `ViewController`. I tried dragging the `button` in my `ViewController` file to create an `@IBAaction func tapped()` but that is not working.

It only works inside of the `ContainerView.swift` file. But I can not create my `Subview` there...

I hope you get my problem, I am grateful for every help!

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("add Button")         
}
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your screen? that would help!

Comment: sure here you go.

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using NotificationCenter and Delegates. Here is how you can achieve it with NotificationCenter

In your ContainerViewController you can post notification on button click

```
@IBAction func yourBtnTap(sender : UIButton) { 
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("myBtnTapped"), object: nil)
}
```

In your CurrentViewController you have to first register to receive this notification. So in your viewDidLoad, do this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myBtnTappedAction(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("myBtnTapped"), object: nil)
```

Now in your CurrentViewContoller create myBtnTappedAction function that will be called whenever the button is tapped.

```
@objc func myBtnTappedAction(notification : Notification) { 
// now you can perform all your actions here. this function will be called everytime the button in the container view is tapped.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but @Muhamed Gül answers looks simpler to me

Comment: Since I couldn't get the other answer to work I tried and it works perfectly :) Thanks!

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your `ViewController` inside your `ContainerView` using its `parent` property. So, inside your `ContainerView` class:

```
if let parentVC = self.parent as? ViewController {
     parentVC.showSubView() // your method to show the sub view.
}
```

Comment: its not working for me. I can not access any `func` from my `ViewController` in my `ContainerVIew`

Comment: @DieGlueckswurst i've updated the answer, please recheck.

Comment: is thins working for you?? Because I am getting 6 errors :D

Comment: The other answer is actually working for me, even if that's not very smooth

Comment: @DieGlueckswurst Yes it works perfectly. What errors are you getting? I hope you are not trying to use the method named showSubView(), it is just an example. And also i assumed your parent view controller's class is `ViewController` since it looks like that in your question. If not, change `as? ViewController` with `as? YourParentClassName` or whatever name it has.

Comment: In my case its `letPopUpViewAppear` and `ExapleViewController` but I changed that accordingly

Comment: ok I was stupid.. was another mistake. But yours is working now as well. thanks! :)